# str not compatible with StrOrLiteralStr

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

Let's say I have this source code:

```
from string import Formatter
from typing import Iterable, Tuple

class MyFormatter(Formatter):
    def parse(self, s: str) -> Iterable[Tuple[str, str, str, str]]:
        for text, field, spec, conversion in super().parse(s):
            yield "a", "b", "c", "d"
```

mypy complains about it:

`error: Return type "Iterable[tuple[str, str, str, str]]" of "parse" incompatible with return type "Iterable[tuple[StrOrLiteralStr, StrOrLiteralStr | None, StrOrLiteralStr | None, StrOrLiteralStr | None]]" in supertype "Formatter"  [override]`

I don't understand why `str` isn't acceptable for `StrOrLiteralStr`.

What am I missing here and what do I do to fix it?

Comment: FWIW, this code passes type checking in mypy 0.971, and fails in mypy 0.981 through 1.5.0.

Comment: I think it's because you have made the type of your subclass stricter than the type of the parent class. Your actual return value is compatible with the parent's return type, its your annotation that is the problem.

Comment: @Anentropic mypy allows making return values stricter (I've just rechecked)

Comment: Looks like a `mypy` bug to me.

Comment: Perhaps it's related to mypy lack of support for `LiteralStr` https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/12554